# Checkbox content not displaying in the html content of mail in php

Tags: php, html, sql, email, phpmailer

I am trying to store the data of checkboxes in the database and send a mail to the user after submitting the form which contains checkbox content. But, Checkbox content is not visible in the mail. Help me solve this??

HTML Code:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-4">
   <div class="form-check">
      <label class="form-check-label">
          <input class="form-check-input" name="event[]" type="checkbox"  value="All Events">
            <span style="font-size: 15px;">All Events</span>
      </label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-4">
    <div class="form-check">
       <label class="form-check-label">
           <input class="form-check-input" name="event[]" type="checkbox"  value="Wine Tasting Event">
             <span style="font-size: 15px;">Wine Tasting </span> 
       </label>
    </div>
</div>                                          
<div class="col-4">
    <div class="form-check">
        <label class="form-check-label">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="event[]"  value="Shopping Event">
             <span style="font-size: 15px;">Shopping </span>                          
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-4">
    <div class="form-check">
        <label class="form-check-label">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="event[]" value="Basketball Charity Event">
              <span style="font-size: 15px;">Basketball Charity </span>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-4">
    <div class="form-check">
        <label class="form-check-label">
          <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="event[]"  value="As Needed">
               <span style="font-size: 15px;">As Needed</span>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

PHP Code Storing Checkbox Content in Database and sending mail using volunteer_mail function:

```
$event_name = implode(',', $_POST['event']);
$sql = "INSERT INTO volunteers (first_name, last_name, phone_number, email, 
event_name, volunteer_type, street_address) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?);";
$dbcon = mysqli_stmt_init($conn);
if(!mysqli_stmt_prepare($dbcon,$sql)){
 echo "SQL error";
                                    }
else{
      mysqli_stmt_bind_param($dbcon,"sssssss",$first_name,$last_name,$number,                                
      $email,$event_name,$volunteer_type,$address);
       mysqli_stmt_execute($dbcon);
    }
volunteer_mail();
```

Volunteer Mail Function:

```
function volunteer_mail(){

 $mail = new PHPMailer;
 $mail->isSMTP();                                      
 $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';  
 $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               
 $mail->Username = email;                 
 $mail->Password = pass;                           
 $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            
 $mail->Port = 587;                                
 $mail->setFrom(email, 'Detroit Pheniox Center');
 $mail->addAddress($_POST['email']);     // Add a recipient
 $mail->isHTML(true);                                  
 $mail->Subject = 'Volunteer Registration Confirmation';
 $mail->Body = '<html>
      <body style="font-family:Georgia, serif; ">
           <center>
             <div style="width:500px;background-color:#f5f5f5;border: 1px 
             solid #a8a8a8; padding:20px; border-radius:2px;">
             <img src="https://scontent-ort2- 2.cdninstagram.com/vp/dab330c3a04b24bb987abed742147509/5B8ABB80/t51.2885-19/s150x150/26873078_409153092875319_57809469530177536_n.jpg" height="100" width="100" style="border-radius:100%;">
                ';

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM volunteers WHERE email='$email';";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        While($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            $event_array = explode(",", $row['event_name']);
            $count = count($event_array);
            for($i=0;$i<$count;$i++){

                $mail->Body .= '<h4>'. $event_array[$i] . '&nbsp;</h4>';
                        }
                    }



      $mail->Body .='<h3>Hello!&nbsp;'.$_POST['first-name'].'</h3>
      <h3>THANK YOU!</h3> for joining as a volunteer and helping us in the 
      event.


      <p> Looking forward to meet you in the event. </p>
      <div style="padding:20px;background-color: #2c3840;">
        <a  href="http://www.detroitphoenixcenter.org/index.html" 
        style="color:white;">OurWebsite</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a  
        href="https://www.instagram.com/detroitphoenixcenter/" 
        style="color:white;">Intsagram</a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a  
        href="https://www.linkedin.com/company/detroit-phoenix-center" 
        style="color:white;">Linkedin</a>
      </div>
      </div>
      </center>
      </body> 
      </html> ';

      $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail 
      clients';
      $mail->send();

      }
```

When this mail function is done im getting mail but the event checkbox content is not displayed and remaining html is displaying as per in code. Please do help me.

Comment: was that event data storing into DB?

Comment: Actually u can see in html i was storing in an  event array and storing in db as string. It is successfully storing but it is not showing on mail

Comment: do a print_r($mail->body) and put exit before sending email and check whether that data is printing or not